# How do I synchronize Goals/Experiments/etc. between Google Analytics properties?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two Analytics properties: dev/test and production. This is because I don't want my live Analytics to record all the conversions/etc. that I do on my dev/test environments (especially when doing automated testing; this would skew our Analytics drastically!).

The problem is, if I want to test certain Goals/Experiments, I have to set them up in my dev/test Analytics property. Then, when I'm done testing, I have to recreate all of them in my production Analytics property. This is a lot of extra work and involves a high risk of making mistakes (entering the wrong URLs for Experiments, etc.).

How do I go about synchronizing these environments? I can't seem to find an import/export option in Analytics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isn't an import/export option available. However if you're savvy enough, you can use the [Management API - Goal Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtGoalGuide) to import/export.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Going to work on a gem to solve this problem. Thanks!